# Sum of potencies with higher potency as clue

Tags: summation, power-series

I am supposed to calculate the following as simple as possible.

Calcute:
$$1 + 101 + 101^2 + 101^3 + 101^4 + 101^5 + 101^6 + 101^7$$
Tip: $$ 101^8 = 10828567056280801$$

I have absolutely no idea how this tip is supposed to help me.
Do I still have to calculate each potency?
Can I somehow solve it with 101^7 * (1 + 101) = 10828567056280801?

As I am not allowed to use a calculator a simple technique for formulas like the one above would be welcome.

Comment: The result is $11111111_{101}$. Jokes aside, Michael Albanese gave you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1}.$$

Comment: Well, this is more than just a hint...

Comment: @lhf: Maybe it is. Let's see if the OP can handle it from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that made it pretty clear :P
Maybe I just did too much math today, as I already solved some with this formula hours ago ^^
Thank you for making me remember

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Let $S=1 + 101 + 101^2 + 101^3 + 101^4 + 101^5 + 101^6 + 101^7$ and consider $101S$.